# Where in the linux source can I see the exact version?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have downloaded a linux kernel source.

There is the README file.

But it only says

```
Linux kernel release 3.x
```

Where can I find the exact version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top of the main `Makefile` in the kernel source will tell you what version you have:

```
$ head Makefile
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
VERSION = 5
PATCHLEVEL = 6
SUBLEVEL = 0
EXTRAVERSION = -rc1
NAME = Kleptomaniac Octopus
```

From a downloaded tarball, this would mean that the tarball contains the source code for version 5.6.0-rc1.